# How do I stop my pixelated background image from turning blurry when repeated?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a pixel art background that is pixelated normally but as soon as the window is wide enough for it to start repeating the entire image turns blurry.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;

background-size: auto 100%;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

The div element is as simple as follows (React.js):

```
<div className='footer' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Image})` }}></div>
```

I have tried setting the image-rendering to crisp-edges but that did not change anything.

Neither does any of the following that I have found in other threads:

```
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
```

More info:

I have discovered that if I zoom in to the image it is no longer blurry, it is only when I am zoomed out it appears so.
I have tried scaling the image up to have a higher resolution. It makes the problem harder to spot but it does not solve anything.

—————————————————————
I “solved” this (stopped it from bothering me) by using background-size to make the image bigger. Thus hindering it from repeating at all for normal sized displays. The issue would still persist for wider screens though.

Comment: hi, can you provide more of the code? it would help better replicate you question.

Comment: It would help us help you if you could provide a runnable snippet (with an image we can see). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following CSS property to your `.footer` element:

```css
background-position: top left;
```

This will ensure that the image is always aligned to the top-left corner of the container, which can help prevent any blurring or distortion that might occur when the image is repeated.

You can also experiment with different `background-size` values to see if any of them help to mitigate the blurring. For example, you might try setting `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain` to see if either of those options provides a better result.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this `image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;` will help the image not to blurry.

If we use this `image-rendering: pixelated;` 
 Is this answered your question?
 
I hope i could help in some ways.

Comment: I added some code to clarify what I have currently